# How can I load an image on NIOS II?

Tags: c, nios

Well, i'am currently using NIOS II, with Quartus II 12.0 and iam facing some problems.

I would like to know how can I manipulate images on Nios II, if there is any library that would allow me to do so, like to write down pictures, read pixels, and if possible to read an image.

Even tho you dont know how to load the image but you know a graphic library that I could use in it please tell me.

Thanks,
Guiaki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Demonstration project from DE2-115 DVD and got an FAT library, now I can open files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [online text](http://www.scribd.com/doc/73916393/Embedded-SoPC-Design-With-Nios-II-Processor-and-VHDL-Examples) that describes the Nios II VGA controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use read only zip file system library in niosii bsp. It requires image need to be stored in flash memory. You can use c based file manipulation functions to read image